# Custom jQuery Plugin overwriting previous data when called more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

I've written a custom jQuery carousel plugin with the following code:

```
(function( $ ) {
var carouselFunctions = {
    'init' : function( options ) {

        // Set some default options
        var settings = $.extend({
            'width' : false,
            'height' : 200,
            'currentSlide' : false,
            'slideTime' : false,
        }, options);

        // Return each matched element
        return this.each(function() {
            // Create an Array for the Slides
            slideArray = new Array();

            // Loop through and add the slides
            $(' > div', this).each(function() {
                // Add the Slide
                slideArray.push($(this));
            });

            // Wrap it in a Holder
            $(this).addClass('ui-carousel');

            // Determine the Carousel Width
            if (settings.width == false) {
                var cWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
            } else {
                var cWidth = settings.width;
            }

            // Create the Carousel Buttons
            var prevButton = $('<a href="#" class="left prev ui-button ui-icon ui-icon-chevron-left"></a>');
            var nextButton = $('<a href="#" class="right next ui-button ui-icon ui-icon-chevron-right"></a>');

            // Create the Carousel Navigation
            var carouselNav = $('<div class="ui-carousel-navigation"></div>').css({
                'width' : cWidth,
                'margin-top' : (settings.height / 2) - 7,
                'position' : 'absolute'
            });

            // Add the Carousel Buttons
            carouselNav.append(prevButton).append(nextButton);

            // Add the Navigation to the Carousel
            $(this).append(carouselNav);

            // Create the Inner Div
            var carouselInner = $('<div class="ui-carousel-inner"></div>');

            // Set the CSS
            carouselInner.css({
                'width' : (cWidth * slideArray.length),
                'height' : settings.height
            });

            // Add the Inner Container to the Carousel
            $(this).append(carouselInner);

            // Append the Slides
            for (var i in slideArray)
            {
                // Append to the Inner
                slideArray[i].css({
                    'width' : cWidth,
                    'min-height' : settings.height,
                    'vertical-align' : 'top',
                    'display' : 'inline-block'
                }).appendTo(carouselInner);
            }

            // Set the Current and total Slides
            var currentSlide = 0;
            var nextSlide = currentSlide + 1;
            var prevSlide = slideArray.length - 1;
            var totalSlides = slideArray.length;

            // Check whether we have a slide specified
            if (currentSlide !== false)
            {
                // Loop through and Find the Slide
                for (var i in slideArray)
                {
                    // Check the IDs
                    if (currentSlide == slideArray[i].attr('id'))
                    {
                        // Set the Slide Index
                        currentSlide = i;

                        // Set the Next Slide
                        nextSlide = (currentSlide == (totalSlides.length - 1)) ? 0 : i + 1;

                        // Set the Previous Slide
                        prevSlide = (currentSlide == 0) ? slideArray.length - 1 : i - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Blank Interval
            leftInterval = false;

            // Function for Sliding Left
            slideLeft = function() {
                // Set the Margins and Append the Previous Slide to the Array
                slideArray[prevSlide].css('margin-left', 0).appendTo(carouselInner);
                slideArray[nextSlide].css('margin-left', 0);

                // Animate the Slide
                slideArray[currentSlide].animate({ 'margin-left' : -cWidth }, function() {
                    // Increment the Current Slide
                    currentSlide++;

                    // Go to the Beginning Slide if necessary
                    currentSlide = (currentSlide == totalSlides) ? 0 : currentSlide;

                    // Set the Previous and Next Slide
                    prevSlide = ((currentSlide - 1) < 0) ? totalSlides - 1 : currentSlide - 1;
                    nextSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) >= totalSlides) ? 0 : currentSlide + 1;

                    // If we have a Slide Time Specified
                    if (settings.slideTime !== false)
                    {
                        // Clear the Animation Interval
                        window.clearInterval(leftInterval);

                        // Reset the Animation Interval
                        leftInterval = window.setInterval(slideLeft, settings.slideTime);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Function for Sliding Right
            slideRight = function() {
                // Animate the Slide
                slideArray[prevSlide].animate({ 'margin-left' : 0 }, function() {
                    // Move the next slide in place
                    slideArray[nextSlide].css('margin-left', -cWidth).insertBefore(slideArray[prevSlide]);

                    // Decrement the Current Slide
                    currentSlide--;

                    // Go to the End Slide if necessary
                    currentSlide = (currentSlide < 0) ? totalSlides - 1 : currentSlide;

                    // Set the Previous and Next Slide
                    prevSlide = ((currentSlide - 1) < 0) ? totalSlides - 1 : currentSlide - 1;
                    nextSlide = ((currentSlide + 1) >= totalSlides) ? 0 : currentSlide + 1;

                    // If we have a Slide Time Specified
                    if (settings.slideTime !== false)
                    {
                        // Clear the Animation Interval
                        window.clearInterval(leftInterval);

                        // Reset the Animation Interval
                        leftInterval = window.setInterval(slideLeft, settings.slideTime);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Set the Next Function
            nextButton.click(function(e) {
                // Prevent Default Behaviour
                e.preventDefault();

                // Add the Slide Behaviour
                slideLeft();
            });

            // Set the Previous Function
            prevButton.click(function(e) {
                // Prevent Default Behaviour
                e.preventDefault();

                // Add the Slide Behaviour
                slideRight();
            });

            // Set the Initial Timer
            if (settings.slideTime !== false)
            {
                // Set the Slide on a Timer
                leftInterval = window.setInterval(slideLeft, settings.slideTime);
            }
        });
    }
};
$.fn.carousel = function( method ) {
    // Method calling logic
    if ( carouselFunctions[ method ] ) {
        return carouselFunctions[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
        return carouselFunctions.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.carousel' );
    }
};
})( jQuery );
```

The plugin works perfectly when called once, but if I call it multiple times, the slideArray seems to get overwritten.

For example, on a page with the following code:

```
<div id="carousel1">
    <div>Slide 1</div>
    <div>Slide 2</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#carousel1').carousel();
</script>
<div id="carousel2">
    <div>Slide 3</div>
    <div>Slide 4</div>
    <div>Slide 5</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#carousel2').carousel();
</script>
```

When I click on the scroll buttons for carousel1, the slide function performs on carousel2 instead. I did a quick console.log on the click event for the slide buttons, to show the elements of slideArray, and it appears that the slideArray from carousel1 is being overwritten by the slideArray from carousel2.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to declare `slideArray` inside the each scope. At the minute it's an implicitly-declared global variable - that's why it gets overwritten

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer? As far as I can see, the slideArray is being declared in the each scope.

Comment: You're missing the `var` declaration so it's actually only *declared* once but being set each time

Comment: Brilliant, that works now. Also had to add the `var` declaration to the `slideLeft` and `slideRight` functions.